# C++ Programming, delete the duplicate emails from the file and creating a new file without the duplicates,

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, duplicates

I wrote codes for exam score, wondering if how can I use the same code to delete the duplicate email list, I thought I can just change the int to string, and I would be fine, but found out I was wrong,
Please help.

```
      //my main.cpp
     #include<iostream>
    #include<fstream>
    #include "rawlist.dat"
   using namespace std;

   string examScore[250], len;

   void ReadScore()
     {
         //Declares an object of ifstream for reading
         ifstream rfile;
        //Opens the file input.txt in read mode
       rfile.open("rawlist.dat");
        len = 0;
          //Loops till end of the file
           while(!rfile.eof())
         {
           //Reads a character
        rfile>>examScore[len++];
         }//End of while loop
        }//End of read function


 void ShowScore()
 {
         cout<<"\n Exam Score ";
     for (string x = 0; x< len; x++)
    cout<< examscore[x] << " ";
   //Loops till end of array

    cout<<endl;
    }


     void SortScore()
       {
  string Temp, x, y;
 //Loops till end of array
  for(x = 0; x < len; x++)
  {
  //Loops till end of array - current x value - 1
     for(y = 0; y < len - x - 1; y++)
   {
     swap
  if(examScore[y] < examScore[y + 1])
  {
  //Swapping
    Temp = examScore[y];
   examScore[y] = examScore[y + 1];
   examScore[y + 1] = Temp;
   }//End of if
  }//End of for loop for variable y
  }//End of for loop for variable x
 }//End of function


 void BarChart()
  {
 //Loops till end of array
 for(string x = 0; x < len; x++)
  {

  cout<<examScore[x]<<" ";

  for(string y = 0; y < examScore[x]; y++)
  cout<<"*";
  cout<<endl;
 }//End of for loop
   }
  //Main function
  int main()
  {
  ReadScore();
   SortScore();
  ShowScore();
  BarChart();
   }



 //my rwlist.h file
  hello@gmail.com
     hello@gmail.com
    usa@gamil.com
   world@gmail.com
   cplusplus@gmail.com
   light@gmail.com
   world@gmail.com
   light@gmail.com



        Please help, Thank you very very much.
```

Comment: "I thought I can just change the int to string" - what do you mean by that?

Comment: Also note, that include is for the files the compiler has to read for compilation, containing function headers, class definitions. Your data file is not that, so you can't include it... You must have got some errors for that.